# Query not returning child posts for any parent post ID

Tags: query

I have a custom post template on which I want to show a list of other children of this post's parent. I already have the parent post ID in a variable ($parent_artist_id), which is being used elsewhere on the page. Here is my code:

```
    $pastshowargs = array(
      'post_parent' => $parent_artist_id,
      'post_type' => 'shows',
      'numberposts' => -1,
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'orderby' => 'title'
    );

    $child_posts = get_posts($pastshowargs);
    if ( !empty($child_posts) ) {
      echo "<ul>";
      foreach ($child_posts as $child_post) {
        $showname = get_the_title($child_post->ID);
        $parentartistid = wpcf_pr_post_get_belongs($child_post->ID, 'artist');
        echo "<li>" . $showname . " (". $parentartistid . ")</li>";
      }
    echo "</ul>";
    } else { echo "empty"; }
```

The problem is that this produces nothing if I supply an ID for 'post_parent'. If I manually set the ID as '0' or remove that parameter altogether, I get a list of all the 'shows' posts, but putting any number in the post_parent parameter gets me nothing.

Any idea what I've done wrong?

Comment: have you verified that the variable `$parent_artist_id` contains a valid parent id? what happens if you enter any existing parent id as number instead of the variable?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is that for parent/child relationships, I'm using the Toolset Types plugin, which stores the relationships as fields rather than how Wordpress normally thinks of them. This means that when Wordpress looks at a post ID, it doesn't see the child relationships that the plugin does.

To get around this, I used this instead of the 'parent_post' parameter:

```
'meta_query' => array(array('key' => '_wpcf_belongs_artist_id', 'value' => $parent_artist_id ) )
```

This searches in the field that the Types plugin uses to find the post ID.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [wp_list_pages()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_pages) when querying for hierarchical post types. It's a little more geared towards parent/child relationships. It uses [get_pages()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages%20get_pages()) under the hood if you're wondering where it gets its data.